# How related p:outputLabel with more than one p:inputText when required attribute is "true"

Tags: ajax, primefaces, xhtml, required

We normally use outputLabel this way:

`<p:outputLabel value="Name: " for="myname"></p:outputLabel>
<p:inputText id="myname" value="#{mybean.name}"></p:inputText>`

How can I coloured this outputLabel if some of three inputs for example are empty.
I was thinking use p:ajax but i will have to addCss to the label of outputLabel to llok like the normal behavior of outputLabel for a case like this.

Is the only way I imagine, a little help please.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

You can use EL in the style attribute of any input.

> How can I coloured this outputLabel if some of three inputs for example are empty.

This way you do this:

```
<p:inputText id="firstInput" value="#{mybean.name}">
  <p:ajax event="keyup" update="myLabel"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:inputText id="secondInput" value="#{mybean.name2}">
  <p:ajax event="keyup" update="myLabel"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:inputText id="thirdInput" value="#{mybean.name3}">
  <p:ajax event="keyup" update="myLabel"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:outputLabel id="myLabel" value="I change colors!" 
   style="color:#{(empty mybean.name and empty mybean.name2 and empty mybean.name3) ? 'red' : 'black'}"/>
```

The style would be read as: "if name is empty or null and name2 is empty or null and name3 is empty or null then 'red' else 'black'".